# Ubuntu machine crashes randomly but absolutely no log. How to debug it?

Tags: ubuntu, crash, freeze

I am running an ubuntu machine and it crashes randomly. By "crashing" I mean it completely freezes, i.e. no HDD activity, no response to peripherals, and the display output is frozen.

At the moment of the crash, there is no log in the system describing any error or anything at all that takes place every time of the crash.

I have looked at the following logs:

```
All log files are located in /var/log directory. In that directory, there are specific files for each type of logs. For example, system logs, such as kernel activities are logged in syslog file.

Some of the most common log files in that directory is :

In directory apt there is a file history.log which saves all the package installation and removal information even the initial system build as Live CD. You can open this file to see this very interesting file.

In directory dist-upgrade there is a file apt.log which logs the information during distribution upgrades

In directory installer the log files which are created during installation can be found.

There is an apport.log file which saves information about crashes in your system and reporting them.

The file auth.log includes information about the authentication activities such as when you authenticate as root user via sudo.

The file dpkg.log saves the low level details of package installation and removal related with dpkg. You might be aware that the apt system depends on dpkg for package installation and removal.

boot.log includes information of each booting.

kern.log saves kernel information such as warnings, errors etc.

alternatives.log includes the history of all the alternatives set by various packages and their removal via update-alternatives command.

Another important log file is Xorg.log which include information about the graphics driver, its failures, warnings etc.

Some other types of Log files may be there depending on your installed packages. For example, My system also includes a log files epoptes.log which will only be there if you install epoptes package.

Changes after systemd
With the advent of systemd, logging is mostly handled by journalctl utility and store the logs in binary format in /var/lib/systemd/catalog/database file. This file enumerates all logs including kernel, boot and application logs and provides required logs via journalctl utility.

Here is a good article on journalctl on how you can use it to fetch required log info.
```

Things I tried and did not work:

- Different HDDs
- Check memory health with uefi
- Check CPU Health with uefi
- Enable/disable disk encryption
- Different versions of ubuntu
- Enabling/disabling C states
- Different values of memory refresh rates
- A bunch of different permutations of all the settings in the uefi

**Question: Is there anyway I can get a log message to debug this problem?**

System details:

```
uname -a
Linux %%% 5.3.0-46-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 27 17:37:05 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Hardware details

```
    description: Desktop Computer
    product: To Be Filled By O.E.M. (To Be Filled By O.E.M.)
    vendor: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.8 dmi-2.8 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=desktop family=To Be Filled By O.E.M. sku=To Be Filled By O.E.M. uuid=78F29E90-B692-0000-0000-000000000000
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: H110M-STX
       vendor: ASRock
       physical id: 0
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: P8.10
          date: 04/01/2019
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 6MiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 8
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 128KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back data
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:1
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 9
          slot: L1 Cache
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 128KiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back instruction
          configuration: level=1
     *-cache:2
          description: L2 cache
          physical id: a
          slot: L2 Cache
          size: 1MiB
          capacity: 1MiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=2
     *-cache:3
          description: L3 cache
          physical id: b
          slot: L3 Cache
          size: 8MiB
          capacity: 8MiB
          capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
          configuration: level=3
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: c
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: CPUSocket
          size: 3557MHz
          capacity: 3600MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb invpcid_single pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx rdseed adx smap clflushopt intel_pt xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves dtherm arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp md_clear flush_l1d cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=8
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: d
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 32GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
             product: KHX2400C14S4/16G
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 0
             serial: 18044524
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
             size: 16GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
             product: KHX2400C14S4/16G
             vendor: Kingston
             physical id: 1
             serial: 19044024
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
             size: 16GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 05
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=skl_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: HD Graphics 630
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:126 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:124 memory:df110000-df11ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.3.0-46-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.03
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=10 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Keyboard
                   product: USB Receiver
                   vendor: Logitech
                   physical id: 3
                   bus info: usb@1:3
                   version: 29.01
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=98mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: a
                   bus info: usb@1:a
                   version: 0.01
                   capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.3.0-46-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 5.03
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-generic
             description: Signal processing controller
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi cap_list
             configuration: driver=intel_pch_thermal latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:df12e000-df12efff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:127 memory:df12d000-df12dfff
        *-sata
             description: SATA controller
             product: Q170/Q150/B150/H170/H110/Z170/CM236 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 17
             bus info: pci@0000:00:17.0
             logical name: scsi1
             version: 31
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: sata msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list emulated
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:125 memory:df128000-df129fff memory:df12c000-df12c0ff ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:df12b000-df12b7ff
           *-disk
                description: ATA Disk
                product: TOSHIBA THNSNK12
                vendor: Toshiba
                physical id: 0.0.0
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/sda
                version: 4101
                serial: 778S10RHT1UT
                size: 119GiB (128GB)
                capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
                configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=c5ad6057-3899-438f-b2a0-d01e4ed9d913 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
              *-volume:0
                   description: Windows FAT volume
                   vendor: mkfs.fat
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,1
                   logical name: /dev/sda1
                   logical name: /boot/efi
                   version: FAT32
                   serial: 6bc8-b933
                   size: 510MiB
                   capacity: 511MiB
                   capabilities: boot fat initialized
                   configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro name=EFI System Partition state=mounted
              *-volume:1
                   description: EXT4 volume
                   vendor: Linux
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,2
                   logical name: /dev/sda2
                   logical name: /boot
                   version: 1.0
                   serial: 5f514558-2659-4fd3-83f0-5121d5c2b4fb
                   size: 732MiB
                   capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                   configuration: created=2020-04-06 09:41:00 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/boot modified=2020-04-24 09:24:12 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime mounted=2020-04-24 09:24:12 state=mounted
              *-volume:2
                   description: EFI partition
                   physical id: 3
                   bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,3
                   logical name: /dev/sda3
                   serial: d5edebae-120f-4190-9d11-2220c0c419b5
                   size: 118GiB
                   capacity: 118GiB
                   width: 422782464 bits
                   capabilities: encrypted luks initialized
                   configuration: bits=13307684352 filesystem=luks hash=sha256 version=2
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:122
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #7
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.6
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:123 memory:df000000-df0fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak]
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: wlp2s0
                version: 10
                serial: 18:1d:ea:6a:51:b2
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.3.0-46-generic firmware=29.1654887522.0 ip=192.168.43.129 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:128 memory:df000000-df001fff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: H110 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 31
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-memory UNCLAIMED
             description: Memory controller
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 31
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:df124000-df127fff
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
             resources: irq:129 memory:df120000-df123fff memory:df100000-df10ffff
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.4
             version: 31
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:df12a000-df12a0ff ioport:f040(size=32)
     *-pnp00:00
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 1
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:01
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 2
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:02
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 3
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:03
          product: PnP device PNP0b00
          physical id: 4
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
     *-pnp00:04
          product: PnP device INT3f0d
          vendor: Interphase Corporation
          physical id: 5
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:05
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 6
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:06
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 7
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:07
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: e
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:08
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: f
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
```

Comment: Is this system a desktop PC or a server? What I mean is, does it have a desktop PC motherboard or a server motherboard. If it is a server board, you might check if there is a system event log (SEL). You can sometimes find this in the BIOS Setup menu, otherwise if it has a BMC (Baseboard Management Controller), you will find the SEL in there.If you are not sure if there is a BMC, check to see if you have a management NIC port on the back. Some desktop PC motherboards do have a rudimentary SEL. Most likely you'll be able to access it through BIOS Setup.

Comment: @tornado good point. It is a desktop motherboard. I was checking in the bios, I can't find any error log or similar.